# How Can i connect to an LDAP server using following details from java?

Tags: java, ldap, jndi, openldap

I am having following java code but i am getting error
provided details

> password="some";   domain name=ABF.ADDAS.com   user
>   name=SADFA.com\username or SADFA\username

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://ip:389");
            // 
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, ""); 
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call InitialLdapContext with your parameters:

```
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, domainName + "\\" + username);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

try{
    return new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
}
catch(javax.naming.CommunicationException e){
    throw new NamingException("Failed to connect to " + domainName + ((serverName==null)? "" : " through " + serverName));
}
catch(NamingException e){
    throw new NamingException("Failed to authenticate " + username + "@" + domainName + ((serverName==null)? "" : " through " + serverName));
}
```

Comment: LDAP authentication error: LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090334, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, vece

Comment: http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=LDAP_Error_Codes

49 LDAP_INVALID_CREDENTIALS

Comment: Also try `env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username + "@" + domainName);`